# Tweet quote content on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter

I've been trying to find how to do this for hours... 
[Here's](https://jsfiddle.net/hanyb9da/20/) my quote machine. I'm trying to get it to tweet the quote displayed when the twitter button is clicked, but right now all I can get it to do is go to the normal twitter share page by this code:

```
$('#tweet').click(function(){
        window.open("https://twitter.com/share");
    });
```

Thank you!

Comment: What have you tried other than opening a twitter URL?  https://dev.twitter.com/web/intents might be of interest.  As might https://dev.twitter.com/web/tweet-button/parameters which explains what parameters you need in your URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call the following link in your `window.open` statement:

```
 window.open("https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text="+ $('#main-quote').text() +"&via=your-app-name&original_referer=your-url");
```

where:

- `text` is the text to be posted and
- `via` is the optional twitter profile you want to inform in the tweet

Your fiddle in action forked to : https://jsfiddle.net/claykaboom/qyqykdvm/

More info at: https://dev.twitter.com/web/tweet-button/web-intent

Answer (score 1):

Take a look into Twitter's javascript API

https://dev.twitter.com/web/javascript/creating-widgets

Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/k0p7bc2j/ using `createShareButton`:

```
twttr.widgets.createShareButton(
  ' ',
  document.getElementById('new-button'),
  {
    count: 'none',
    text: document.getElementById('quote').value
  }).then(function (el) {
    console.log("Button created.")
  });
```